# Landing midnightish in Russia: Am I stuck?

Tags: air-travel, russia, siberia

I want to go to Siberia (Omsk, Novosibirsk, Tomsk, Krasnoyarsk) and would love to take a nonstop flight.

Sadly, all of the direct flights from airports around me will land between 10 pm and 1 am at the given cities.

Is it advisable to take such a flight - travelling on my own with only lower intermediate knowledge of the Russian language?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whether or not it's advisable is totally up to you - it's a subjective question and each person is different, so we can't answer that aspect.

It'll be difficult, so accept that now and enjoy the ride ;)

I've flown into Novosibirsk, and there were taxis from the airport. So as long as you have the name of your accommodation (or address), preferably written in Cyrillic, you can get by quite easily.

Walk up to a taxi, he'll obviously want to know where you're going. Show him the paper with the location on it, and ask "skolka?" (how much)? He'll reply in Russian, you won't know what it is, look lost, and he'll likely write it down, or type it on his phone.  Make sure you get the price before getting in the cab - even if only an estimate.

When you get there, pay, and voila, you've made it to your accommodation (Assuming you have some).

Alternative option: try and befriend a local, if you can, and get a ride with them.

Final option: [Sleep at the airport](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/novosibirsk.htm), and get a taxi during the day. The airport has showers, and as per the link, it's definitely possible to sleep there, just be careful about your stuff.

For more information on taxi prices and the bus option, have a look at the [Get In section on Wikitravel for Novosibirsk](http://wikitravel.org/en/Novosibirsk#Get_in).

Comment: important addition: make sure you notify the accommodation of your estimated late arrival time, or you might find the doors locked and only a night guard on duty who's not going to let you in. That's the case in most of the world, not just Russia.

Comment: I wouldn't say "most of the world" though it is certainly common. Most of Eastern Europe for instance had hostels with 24-hour check in. Big hostels in Australian capitals do but the one I work at in Sydney does not.

Comment: @hippietrail true, probably there's a mix anywhere. But from my experience all hotels like to be notified of late arrivals even if they have 24/7 checkin and many will assume you're not coming and may rent out the room you booked to someone else if you miss the "normal" 10am to 4pm checkin window.

Comment: Yes some accommodation offers 24 hour check-in where you can just turn up any time, but many other places even if they don't advertise 24 hour check-in have contingency plans if you prearrange a "late check-in". Again my experience is with hostels rather than hotels, which may well differ.

Comment: re: the taxi bit: there was/is a somewhat popular scam to name a price for the ride, then, at the end of the journey, to claim that the price was per kilometer, not the full distance.